# What is the required coder parameter in this view controller and what do I put there?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have used UISearch controller before, but I have never see it ask me for a coder as a parameter. I have left the argument blank where I am having trouble, in "let searchVC = ..." I think it is because the view controller I am using it in requires a initializer but I'm am not sure

```
class SpotIdSearchViewController: UIViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, SpotIdSearchResultsViewControllerDelegate {
    
    private var urls = [URL]()
    
    private var image: UIImage?
    
    let searchVC = UISearchController(searchResultsController: SpotIdSearchViewController(coder: ))
    
    init(urls: [URL], image: UIImage) {
        self.urls = urls
        self.image = image
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

UIKit view objects can be created (deserialized) by Storyboards and XIBs. That requires that they implement the `init(coder:)` method.

The `NSCoder` parameter is the object used for deserializing view objects out of Storyboards/XIBs.

Comment: so what should I put in parameter?

Comment: also I am not using storyboard I have done everything programatically

Comment: The implementation in your question where you call fatalError is appropriate if you do not want your view/view controller to ever be able to be created in a storyboard or XIB.

Comment: @jasoninthecloud are you talking about when you're actually instantiating it? Just use the other initializer. You're not forced to use the `init(coder:)` one in your code.